# Layering textures on terrain in three.js

Tags: javascript, three.js, textures, webgl, terrain

I have a large terrain, and I would like to lay a low-resolution satellite image across the whole thing.

Then, in areas near the user, I would like to blend in a higher resolution texture of terrain features.

Is texture splatting the best way to do this or is there a better way?  ([Texture splatting with Three.js](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18880715/texture-splatting-with-three-js/18994814#18994814))

Answer (score 2):

Well to apply a texture on your heightmap, I will sugest you use the `THREE.ImageUtils.loadTexture` feature. Please note, that you will need to have the texture in jpg, and not tiff. See [this](http://blog.thematicmapping.org/2013/10/textural-terrains-with-threejs.html) . The code is in [github](https://github.com/turban/webgl-terrain/blob/master/texture/jotunheimen.html).

For changing the grid resolution to accomodate for high resolution in front, you may want to use cariayble LOD algorithms, one example can be found [here](http://felixpalmer.github.io/lod-terrain/).