# Setting texture to geometry in Three.js

Tags: three.js, glsl

I have this geometry: [Picture](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Awsdn.png)

I want to add the same effect that mountains are with snow texture and so on:
[Texture splatting with Three.js](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18880715/texture-splatting-with-three-js)

Little background what info I give to shaders from Three.js:

```
//importing grass and snow textures:
var grassTexture = new THREE.ImageUtils.loadTexture( 'images/grass-512.jpg' );
grassTexture.wrapS = grassTexture.wrapT = THREE.RepeatWrapping;
var snowTexture = new THREE.ImageUtils.loadTexture( 'images/snow-512.jpg' );
snowTExture.wrapS = snowTExture.wrapT = THREE.RepeatWrapping;

this.customUniforms = {
 grassTexture:  { value: grassTexture },
 snowTexture:   { value: snowTexture },

};
var customMaterial = new THREE.ShaderMaterial({
 uniforms: customUniforms,
 side: THREE.DoubleSide,
 vertexShader:   document.getElementById( 'vertexShader'   ).textContent,
 fragmentShader: document.getElementById( 'fragmentShader' ).textContent,
});
//creating mesh, geometry is the model in picture.
mesh = new THREE.Mesh(geometry, customMaterial);
```

Vertex and fragment shaders:

```
//vertexShader:
varying vec2 vUV;

void main(){
 vUV = uv;
 gl_Position = projectionMatrix * modelViewMatrix * vec4( position, 1.0 );
}
```

I get full red model with this:

```
//fragmentShader:
void main(){
 gl_FragColor = vec4(1, 0.0, 0.0, 1.0) ;
}
```

I want textures that are higher with snowTexture and lower with grassTexture.

```
uniform sampler2D grassTexture;  
uniform sampler2D snowTexture;
varying vec2 vUV;
//Something like this?:
vec4 grass = texture2D( grassTexture, vUV);
vec4 snow = texture2D( snowTexture, vUV);
gl_FragColor = vec4(0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 1.0) + grass + snow;
```

Comment: What is the content of `bumpTexture`? Does it contain normal vectors and/or displacement height? If it is a plane geometry, then you can do. `newPosition  = position + normalize(bumpnormal) * bumpheight);`. This will work if the geometry consists of a tessellated plane and the normal vector of the plane in model space is (0, 0, 1). More exact, if the normal vectors from the map are in model space.

Comment: Basically i want the vertexshader to go through all the already created vertices, not move them anywhere, right now when I applied it, it creates a whole new set of vertices. BumpTexture contains my texture from three.js that I loaded with loader function

Comment: It's very hard to understand what you mean in OP and what you mean by "go through all vertices", I suggest that you edit your post and try to make it more clear. The link you provided uses a texture as a displacement map to controls the height of the vertices. If this is not what you want, then perhaps this is not a good starting point.

Comment: Okay, I changed it, maybe now you can understand better.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This really not that hard to understand, let me walk you through the logic.

In your case, you don't want to use a displacement map. So, you need to set up a `varying height` on your vertexShader to map your vertices up-coordinates [0,1] to your fragmentShader.

```
//vertexShader:
varying vec2 vUV;
varying float height;

void main() {

  vUV = uv;

  float maxPosition = 30.0; // this is an example value.
  height = max( 0.0, min(1.0, position.y/maxPosition ) ); // assuming +y is up

  gl_Position = projectionMatrix * modelViewMatrix * vec4( position, 1.0 );

}
```

Now you can access `height` from your fragmentShader and use that information to select where you want your transitions to occur.

```
uniform sampler2D grassTexture;  
uniform sampler2D snowTexture;

varying vec2 vUV;
varying float height;

void main(){

  vec4 grass = (1.0 - smoothstep( 0.48, 0.52, height)) * texture2D( grassTexture, vUV);
  vec4 snow =  (smoothstep(0.48, 0.52, height) - 0.0) * texture2D( snowTexture, vUV);

  gl_FragColor = vec4(0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 1.0) + grass + snow;

}
```

The link provided uses function [smoothstep](https://thebookofshaders.com/glossary/?search=smoothstep) to make a gradual transition between the textures. We can create transitions using the follow pattern `( a - b ) * textureColor`.

In this case, `a` controls when the texture starts to contribute to the fragment color. 
`b` controls when the texture stops contributing.

In other words, your grass texture will have already started contributing at every height, so we map `a` to 1.0. It stops contributing around 0.5, so we give `b` a smooth fade-out as it approaches that 0.5.

Your snow texture, on the other hand, will only start contributing around 0.5. So, we give `a` a smooth fade-in as it approaches 0.5. It will never stop contributing, so we set `b` as 0.0.

Hope this clears things up for you.

Comment: Glad I was able to help.

Comment: I have a follow up question, how can I make it that sand start from 0 and goes to 10% height, grass takes over to 40% and so on to the top, not value, because every time I make my mountains taller, the textures is just like one is like 99% the other is for 1%. I made my z heights to always start from 0. In the link example, he bumps up the scale and it seems like the % of textures stay the same..

Comment: You are correct, we are mapping the % manually. Since you don't want the displacement map. This needs to be updated every time you change the maximum height of your geometry. You could pass a maxHeight uniform from your .js code to inform these changes, instead of having to alter inside the GLSL

Comment: to map a new texture, you use the same pattern I specified above. `sand = ( 1.0 - smoothstep( 0.38, 0.42, height) ) * texture2D`. Then you need to update your the grass texture to only start at 40%. I suggest that you experiment with the pattern I provided, I won't be able to keep helping indefinitely.

Comment: 1 last question, i get the sand part and that, but when i bring it my uniform with value do i need to ```height= position.z/ value.

Comment: I dont get the min and max too i removed it and it did nothing :D only add some square looking meshes not smooth. okay thanks i dont bother you anymore :)