# How to make a smooth texture transition in three.js

Tags: javascript, three.js, 3d, textures, blender

I was able to do this in Blender, my goal is to have a smooth transition between two texture. I did this because I'd like to avoid having a huge 8k texture on the ground.

However, it is not possible to export this in a GLTF file, so I tried to do this in Three.js unsuccesfully. I have no clue what approach to take.

[image: Blender node editor]

This is the best result I was able to get so far. This is by directly importing the .gltf from the screenshot above inside Three.js
[image: Three.js render]

Comment: The technique you're describing is called "Texture splatting", and you'd need to do a bit of custom shaders to achieve the desired result. There's an explanation of it here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18880715/texture-splatting-with-three-js

Comment: There are also some conversations in the Three.js forum that you might find useful: Here is [number one](https://discourse.threejs.org/t/basic-texture-splatting-need-help/2631), and this is [number two](https://discourse.threejs.org/t/how-to-create-a-multiple-textured-terrain/5069).